# Cosmology constant as a negative pressure?

Tags: cosmology, pressure, space-expansion, universe, cosmological-constant

It seems a positive cosmology constant behaves like a negative pressure. However, the positive cosmology constant cause a expanding universe. So I am puzzling about this:

A negative pressure cause a expanding universe?

To me, it is easy to imagine the positive pressure cause expanding just like gas.
Could you give me a explanation about this?

Answer (score 3):

It does seem odd, but this is because in GR the Einstein tensor is proportional to the [stress-energy tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) not just the mass. This is (commonly represented as) a 4x4 matrix and the dominant term is usually the energy density, $T_{00}$. However the other diagonal components $T_{11}$, $T_{22}$ and $T_{33}$ are the pressure. A positive pressure behaves like a mass and causes an attraction. Luboš Motl went into some detail on this in his answer to [Why does pressure act as a source for the gravitational field?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3688/why-does-pressure-act-as-a-source-for-the-gravitational-field). A negative pressure has the opposite effect i.e. it causes a repulsion.

I've rather glossed over why pressure has a similar effect to energy density, because this isn't easy to explain in simple terms. John Baez had a go [here](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/gr/stress.energy.html), though I'm not sure I find this terribly convincing.

Comment: Hi John, thank you for answering. It is good point to understand pressure as some kind of mass, or equivalently speaking the energy density. But I am still wondering "Does the analog of gas make sense here?" I mean the first picture in my mind when I see “negative pressure” is a shrinking bubble. I don't know if the pressure here means some real force in the universe.

Comment: @YingfeiGu It's not an 'analog'. It IS pressure causing attraction/repulsion. But in most circumstances the effects of pressure are completely overshadowed so its negligible. In gases, even gravitation is (mostly) negligible, needless to say pressure!

Answer (score 0):

An oversimplified view on it: Imagine the universe as a 2D sphere. If you add positive pressure (locally or globally), it tends to crumple the sphere where it acts, that is to increase its curvature. And greater curvature means a lesser sphere. And the opposite way for negative pressure.